# 'meet in the middle' combined with Dynamic Programming for subset sum

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, np-complete, subset-sum

What is the reason why nobody has combined the 'meet in the middle' approach with the Dynamic Programming for subset sum?

I found it curious that is a kind of a open problem.. as a matter of fact I never have seen both them combined.

On a paper (1), the author questions if by their combination would be possible to obtain an algorithm with time complexity $O(T^{1/2}*n^{O(1)})$.

Is that time complexity something reasonable?

Could it get better or worse than the above estimation?

(1) SETH-Based Lower Bounds for Subset Sum and Bicriteria Path, Amir Abboud et al. [arXiv:1704.04546](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04546v1)

Comment: I think that in the first sentence you mean "nobody" rather than "anybody".

Comment: Perhaps people have tried and failed?

Comment: (edited the question to correct my mistake)

Comment: @Yuval perhaps, another possibility, is , if somebody found how to do it, that the final time complexity was not the one expected, do this count as a failure?

Comment: Any improvement on the state-of-the-art would have been published. That's how our community works.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I integrated both..., and this is the best I got (so far...), assuming $t = \frac{2^p \cdot n}{2}$, and $\frac{t}{2^p} = \frac{2^p \cdot n \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{2^p} = \frac{n}{2}$. The pseudo-polynomial DP part is effective for densities higher than $d \approx 2.17$, and the Time Complexity is $\mathcal{O}(2^p \cdot (\frac{t/2^p}{4}) ) = \mathcal{O}(\frac{2^p \cdot n}{8}) = \mathcal{O}(2^p \cdot n)$, for the meet in the middle, is not that much of improvement yet, right now the algorithm gets half of the steps required at most, I'm still working on that piece...